# count(*) yielding different results for normal select statement and for triggers

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, triggers, count

I'm having a weird problem in SQLDeveloper.

I have a normal select statement as in: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM demo WHERE NAME='ABC';`
The above query gives a result 1.
Running the same select query as in : `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM demo WHERE NAME='ABC      ';` gives a result 1 as well. Note that the extra appended spaces in the second query doesn't change the value of the count.

Now, having the count(*) statement inside a trigger yields different count results and it takes the spaces into consideration while evaluating the count. 
Why exactly is this happenening? I'm using SQLDeveloper Version 4.1.5.21.

Comment: Are you sure that the query you ran really has those extra spaces?  My first guess would be that you did not run the query you think you did.

Comment: I'm sure I ran query with extra spaces. I have tried the same two queries(with and without spaces)  multiple times.

Comment: I have no explanation but this must be a known problem.

Comment: What is the datatype of column `NAME`? Is it `CHAR(..)` (instead of `VARCHAR2(..)`)?

Comment: Does this happen if you run the query in SQL*Plus?

Comment: The only immediate way I can see this happening is if the column is char and your trigger is using a varchar2 variable in the query, rather than a string literal. Showing your table definition and trigger code would be useful.

Comment: Thank you all. The table column was indeed a char and I was declaring a variable in the trigger with varchar2. Changing the datatype solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this if your column is `char` rather than `varchar2`:

```
create table demo (name char(9));

insert into demo values ('ABC');

1 row inserted.

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM demo WHERE NAME='ABC';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM demo WHERE NAME='ABC      ';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1
```

If you do exactly the same queries in a trigger - or any PL/SQL block - using the same text literals you get the same result:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  n number;
begin
  SELECT COUNT(*) into n FROM demo WHERE NAME='ABC'; 
  dbms_output.put_line(n);
  SELECT COUNT(*) into n FROM demo WHERE NAME='ABC      ';
  dbms_output.put_line(n);
end;
/

1
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But if you use a `varchar2` variable to supply the value instead of a text literal you get different counts:

```
declare
  n number;
  v varchar2(9);
begin
  v := 'ABC';
  SELECT COUNT(*) into n FROM demo WHERE NAME=v; 
  dbms_output.put_line(n);
  v := 'ABC      ';
  SELECT COUNT(*) into n FROM demo WHERE NAME=v;
  dbms_output.put_line(n);
end;
/

0
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

When you use a text literal [it is treated as a `char`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218):

> - Within expressions and conditions, Oracle treats text literals as though they have the data type CHAR by comparing them using blank-padded comparison semantics.

The apparent behaviour difference then comes down to [blank-padded and nonpadded comparison semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF51037):

> With blank-padded semantics, if the two values have different lengths, then Oracle first adds blanks to the end of the shorter one so their lengths are equal.
>   ...
>   Oracle uses nonpadded comparison semantics whenever one or both values in the comparison have the data type VARCHAR2 or NVARCHAR2.

When you compare your `char` column with the (`char`) text literal, both are padded to the same length, so both conditions evaluate to true. With blank-padded semantics, `'ABC'`, `'ABC '`, `'ABC  '` etc. are all equivalent.

When you compare your `char` columns with the `varchar2` variable no padding occurs, so only the second condition - which is manually padded to exactly the same length as the actual column value - evaluates to true. The padded column value `'ABC      '` only matches the variable when it is explicitly set to exactly the same. It is not equal to just `'ABC'` or anything else.

It's generally much simpler to use `varchar2` for your text columns to avoid these oddities. It's unusual (in my experience anyway) to need to use fixed-length strings, and if the length of the data will vary then `varchar2` is more flexible and will use less storage.